# Preventing resize of button in contenteditable div in IE

Tags: javascript, html, resize, contenteditable

We have a styled disabled input, of type button, which we're using as a placeholder for other content in a content editable area. The issue is that IE (we're specifically targeting IE10) appears to ignore the resizestart event altogether so when you click on the element, you're allowed to resize it. We want to prevent that, but still allow the element to be selected and dragged. This does seem to work for the image.

The story behind the choice of element here is long winded, so for now just assume we can't change the element.

UPDATE:
Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5swkeqh9/1/) demonstrating the issue and the relevant sample code here:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <input type="button" value="test" disabled="disabled" onresizestart="return false;" onresize="return false;" id="test" />
</div>
```

Comment: No code? Whatsoever?

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, but please in the future let me know why you're downvoting the question, otherwise I can only make assumptions about how to fix my question.

Comment: @myfunkyside Totally forgot to include the fiddle. Sorry about that and thanks for the comment!

Comment: @myfunkyside Not sure if that was an accidental repost of your comment or not, but the HTML is the relevant code. The event handlers are registered inline intentionally.

Comment: You don't want to use jQueryUI's `.draggable()` and `.droppable()`? I've never used them myself, just thinking it might get around the problem.

Comment: Yeah that was a bug.. the first time I clicked 'Add Comment' it said there was an error and comment wasn't posted. So I clicked again and apparently both times got posted after all... I've removed the second comment now

Comment: see if this helps: http://nickw101.wordpress.com/2011/02/25/disabling-image-resizing-in-ie-contenteditable-elements/

Comment: @MikeWillis Drag and drop aren't really our focus here; we need the content editable because this is for content authoring so I don't think that will solve the resize issue here. Thanks though!

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Thanks for that trick, doesn't seem to work with the input tag though :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is far from ideal, but works. You can capture "mouseup" event of the *container* and reset width and height of the control there:

```
$('#container').mouseup(function(e){
    var $btn = $("#test");
    $btn.css('width','');
    $btn.css('height','')
})
```

This doesn't remove resizing squares and visually user can temporarily resize the control but as soon as  mouse button is released - control snaps to the original size.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5swkeqh9/2/**

Comment: In *IE v11.0.9600.17358* this does work for me on the input button, but not on the image (I know OP specifically targets IE10, but thought I'd just give a heads up)

Comment: We ended up implementing this methodology and it works for us for now. Thanks!